# C++ class object initialization

Tags: c++

Am new to C++ and want to know how the call to class A constructor is made, since the B's default constructor is not initializing A.
NOTE: Class B is not inherited from Class A

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    A() { cout << "A's Constructor Called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{
    A a;
    public:
    B() { cout << "B's Constructor Called " << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B b1;
    return 0;
}

Output is :
A's Constructor Called
B's Constructor Called
```

Comment: " the B's default constructor is not initializing A" - Yes, it is: "A's Constructor Called". For details of why and how this happens, refer to your C++ textbook.

Comment: you posted output shows that your description is wrong. B's constructor clearly called A's constructor. The output from it is right there

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't tell B how to construct its data member `a`, it will use A's default constructor.   If A ddn't have a default constructor, it would be a compiler error.  To call a non-default constructor for `a` from B's constructor, see the code below:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    A() { cout << "A's Constructor Called " << endl;  }
    A(int) {  cout << "A's int Constructor Called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{
    A a;
    public:
    B() { cout << "B's Constructor Called " << endl; }
    B(int i) : a(i) { cout << "B's int Constructor Called " << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B b1;
    B b1(1); // this would call the two new constructors
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you xaxxon for the reply. I want to understand the line "B will automatically call to A's default constructor before starting the constructor for B". How the compiler knows which initialization it has to make inside B. Does it parses all the member variable of B class before constructing B

Comment: In inheritance, the parent class (or classes) will be constructed before the derived classes.   This is just a rule of the language.

Comment: Am not inheriting class B from class A

Comment: Oh crap.  You're right.   Because you did not specify how to construct the data member `a` in the class B, B will construct it using A's default constructor.   Changed my answer from A(i) to a(i).

Comment: Class B is not inherited from A so I want to understand the line "B will automatically call to A's default constructor before starting the constructor for B". How the compiler knows which initialization it has to make inside B. Does it parses all the member variable of B class before constructing B?

Comment: @user6882413: Yes, the compiler parses all the members of the class, and then generates the code for each method. At that point, it knows all the members and their order, and it'll construct the members in order, using the default constructors unless otherwise specified.

Comment: and the data members are done in a specific order and then destructed in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of class B initializes all members of the class, in particular the `A a`. As class A has a constructor, it will be called when class B is instantiated before the code in the constructor is run. That means that the code in the constructor has access to all the initialized members of B. Therefor, as you observed, the construction of an object of class B first calls the construction of the object a of class A and then gives the output about B's constructor.

Comment: How the constructor of class B initializes all members of the class? B's default constructor is having only cout.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something like below and finally able to figure it out.

Constructor meant for setting an initial state of object. In case of inheritance hierarchy, base class objects will be constructed in the order of inheritance hierarchy (IS-A relation in OO terminology) followed by derived class objects.

Similarly when an object is embedded in another object (HAS-A relation in OO terms or containment), constructors of embedded object are called in the order of their declaration.

In the above case, A is embedded in B. A's constructor to be called to setup state of 'a', prior to constructing 'b1' object.